# JQPlot chart library program execution

Tags: jqplot

I am also trying the above code locally.

here is the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuery/excanvas.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuery/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuery/jquery.jqplot.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuery/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuery/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuery/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuery/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuery/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../JQuery/jquery.jqplot.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function(){  
        var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart3', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
      }); 
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart3" style="width:400px; height:300px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I run this code, it gives me javascript error for "excanvas.js" file. like "parentnode" is null or not an object. I am using IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the code and it works fine. 
To be 100% honest I run it in ie9 with compatibility mode of ie8, then ie7 (since I update my browsers regularly, I recommend doing the same and asking clients to do the same as well) and it works fine.

The only issue I might expect you can have here is that these scripts:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuery/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuery/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuery/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuery/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JQuery/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>
```

... are located in **plugins folder** which you should have if you downloaded the `jqPlot` from their site.

To **test quickly if this is the issue** you can simple delete the aforementioned scripts and the code should work just fine as it is not using them at all.

Comment: Hi Boro, i have downloaded jqplot from jqplot site and yes, it's working fine now.  thanks for the details!!